# How get enabled script languages in elasticsearch?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, httprequest

What http request should I made to elasticsearch to get all script languages which elasticsearch instance supports?

Comment: add comment when downvote

Comment: ES supports getting information about all indexes why I can not get information about all scripting languages which are supported? Or it is a credo to downvote any general questions regardless of fact that they can have only one answer exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the installed scripting languages on a special ES node instance. You want to get a list via http-Request:

In 5.6. ["painless" and "groovy" are the default spripting languages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) (and only painless is recommended).
For all other languages ES needs a plugin. So your question is about "how to list all plugins".

You can list all plugins via [shell](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/listing-removing-updating.html#_listing_plugins) or with http via [nodes info api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/cluster-nodes-info.html#plugins-info).